# Springs acting on a car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, string

I am trying to solve a problem but I can't figure out why the answer comes out to be what it is: A man of 80kg enters a car and compresses the 4 springs of the car, causing a change of 1,2cm from their equilibrium position. Knowing that the mass of the car is 900kg without the man, what is the oscillatory frequency of the motion?

My first attempt was to add up the forces acting on each spring, so that
$$F=-4kx\Leftrightarrow mg=-4kx,$$
 but as it turns out I have to consider $mg=-kx$. Why don't we have to add up the forces? Shouldn't the weight be distributed over the four springs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know $$f_n=\frac1{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac km}$$

We then ask ourselves what is k and m. For this case, mass is $980kg$. Is k stiffness of 1 spring or 4 spring? The 980kg mass is not sitting on 1 spring. So it should be 4 spring. The tricky part is we don't use 4k. Instead we use k for stiffness equivalent to 4 springs. With 80kg, we get 1.2cm deflection. So it is easy to get the stiffness. $k = 80kg \cdot 9.8m/s^2/1.2cm=65333N/m$

Thus the natural frequency is 1.3Hz. This is pretty low. But you can try it out on your car by push down bumper and release it at about 1-2Hz frequency. You can your car will response. I saw a guy doing this when he tried to buy my used car to see if my suspension spring works well.

Comment: Alright now I understand! The fact that we use k equivalent only means that the 4 strings are implicit in the resulting k value, so then we can do the normal maths... Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You need the effective spring constant of the four springs in parallel and then use the whole mass of the car to consider the motion of the car or use the spring constant of one spring and use a quarter of the mass of the car.

Comment: But how is it different from having only one spring? I mean, what's the poing of having four springs? To reduce constant spring of each one?

Comment: You have a spring and a damper at each "corner" of a car to provide the suspension.